# Android SeekBar setMax() and incrementProgressBy() not working

Tags: android, increment, seekbar

I do LayoutInflator in a TableRow. (FYI)

In this I do the following:

```
((SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe)).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
((SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe)).setTag(i);
((SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe)).setProgress(0);
```

These things work and my app runs fine.  However, when I do the following, it seems to crash.

```
((SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe)).incrementProgressBy(1);
((SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe)).setMax(10);
```

Then,

```
ArrayList<View> myViews = new ArrayList<View>();
myViews.add(tr1);
```

If anyone knows what the problem is, I would really appreciate your help. 
Thanks,

Comment: did you try to swap order of calls to call setMax first and then incementProgressBy?

Comment: What's the crash? Post the logcat. Some more code wouldn't hurt also, context is always good.

Comment: @Berťák, I did. No help.

Comment: @Geobits, the log cat shows I have a arrayindexoutofbounds in myViews.  Take a look at the edited question.

Comment: You guys should understand, that the error only happens when I add the incrementProgressBy and setMax. :(

Comment: @SohelMansuri what type is myViews? Did you specify the size of myViews initially? +1 for more contextual code.

Comment: @ataulm, take a look at my edit.

Comment: @SohelMansuri Thanks. Could you also post the logcat - either here or link to it from Pastebin or something.

Comment: i would also try to use SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)tr1.findViewById(R.id.seekBarMe);
seekBar.setProgress(
 seekBar.getProgress()+1
); but maybe it will not work, then nevermind my comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the SeekBar onProgressChanged() gets invoked before you add anything to myViews ArrayList.

So, it gives an IndexOutOfBounds exception because you access myViews in the onProgressChanged().

Now you shall work on the onProgressChanged() code so that it doesn't access myViews until the size is greater than 0.

:)